# When will navigator.language different to navigator.languages[0]?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, webview

I am studing browser fingerprint. The js worked in app's webview will detect whether users lied on language by get the result of `navigator.language.substr(0,2) == navigator.languages[0].substr(0,2)`.

We found there are about 3% users lied on language( `navigator.language.substr(0,2) != navigator.languages[0].substr(0,2)`).
By useragent, we found those mobile devices are:

- some HUAWEI mobile phone(with Android 5.1, Android 6.0, Android 7.0, Android 8.0.0 ...)
- some iPhone(with OS 9_1, OS 4_3_2, OS 5_1_1, OS 5_0 ...)
- ...

Does those users lied on language? Is there any device's or browser's reason will result in `navigator.language.substr(0,2) != navigator.languages[0].substr(0,2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the [browser compatibility information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages#Browser_compatibility). There it says:

> In Chrome, `navigator.language` is the language of the browser UI, and is not guaranteed to be equal to `navigator.languages[0]`.
>
> In Firefox, the `navigator.languages` property's value is taken from the `intl.accept_languages` preference.

It also says Safari is fully compatible, but perhaps older versions aren't?